# Unable to configure HTTPS endpoint error with .Net 5.0 WebApi with Docker and https on MacOs

Tags: macos, docker, .net-core

I am trying to get a containerized WebApi up and running in docker on MacOS using the instructions [here](https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker/blob/main/samples/run-aspnetcore-https-development.md)

So far I have a Dockerfile that looks like this:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0
COPY MyApi/bin/Release/net5.0/publish/ App/
WORKDIR /App
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "MyApi.dll"]
```

I am building my container like this:

```
docker build -t my-app-api .
```

and I am trying to start the container like this:

```
docker run -it -p 40080:80 -p 40443:443 -e ASPNETCORE_URLS="https://+;http://+" -e ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT=40443 -e ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development -v ${HOME}/.microsoft/usersecrets/:/root/.microsoft/usersecrets/ -v ${HOME}/.aspnet/https/:/root/.aspnet/https/ my-app-api
```

When I run the above command, I am running into this error:

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[0]
      Unable to start Kestrel.
      System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to configure HTTPS endpoint. No server certificate was specified, and the default developer certificate could not be found or is out of date.
      To generate a developer certificate run 'dotnet dev-certs https'. To trust the certificate (Windows and macOS only) run 'dotnet dev-certs https --trust'.
      For more information on configuring HTTPS see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=848054.
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ListenOptionsHttpsExtensions.UseHttps(ListenOptions listenOptions, Action`1 configureOptions)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ListenOptionsHttpsExtensions.UseHttps(ListenOptions listenOptions)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.AddressesStrategy.BindAsync(AddressBindContext context)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.BindAsync(IEnumerable`1 listenOptions, AddressBindContext context)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServerImpl.BindAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServerImpl.StartAsync[TContext](IHttpApplication`1 application, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
Unhandled exception. System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to configure HTTPS endpoint. No server certificate was specified, and the default developer certificate could not be found or is out of date.
To generate a developer certificate run 'dotnet dev-certs https'. To trust the certificate (Windows and macOS only) run 'dotnet dev-certs https --trust'.
For more information on configuring HTTPS see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=848054.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ListenOptionsHttpsExtensions.UseHttps(ListenOptions listenOptions, Action`1 configureOptions)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ListenOptionsHttpsExtensions.UseHttps(ListenOptions listenOptions)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.AddressesStrategy.BindAsync(AddressBindContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.BindAsync(IEnumerable`1 listenOptions, AddressBindContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServerImpl.BindAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServerImpl.StartAsync[TContext](IHttpApplication`1 application, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostService.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.Host.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.RunAsync(IHost host, CancellationToken token)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.RunAsync(IHost host, CancellationToken token)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.Run(IHost host)
```

I have tried clearing the user secrets and deleting the certificate from my KeyChain and regenerating it with no change in behaviour. The app also works when I run locally from Visual Studio and access it with https.

Comment: When you do a bind mount of a directory, the host path needs to be absolute. The tutorial says you should do `-v ${HOME}/.microsoft/usersecrets/:/root/.microsoft/usersecrets` but you've made a relative path using `-v ~/.microsoft/usersecrets/:/root/.microsoft/usersecrets`

Comment: You are right, though I’ve tried it both ways and they produce the same error.

Comment: Have you tried running through the sample doc at https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker/blob/main/samples/run-aspnetcore-https-development.md and seeing how your app/environment differs from that?

Comment: @MattThalman Yes, that's the one I linked in the question. How does my environment differ except for the ${HOME} variables mentioned above? I will update my question to add the ${HOME} variable since I tried it that way first.